# MS Access: Showing a non specific Table on a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

Is it possible to show a table on a form, by selecting it with a ComboBox?

For example: I have a ComboBox in which the user can select any Table from the DB. After selecting a specific Table the columns of the Table shall be shown in a list on the form.

I hope you understand my problem :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an **empty** subform control on your main form. Name it e.g. `subformTable`.

Then in the `AfterUpdate` event of the combobox, set the `SourceObject` property to `Table.yourtable`:

```
Me.subformTable.SourceObject = "Table." & Me.cboTables
```

Comment: A source object of type Table can only be in datasheet view, I think. At least I didn't have to set any property.

Comment: The table view type is determined by its "Default View" setting --- which is a property of the table, not of the subform control.  Generally that setting is "Datasheet".  But it you change the setting to something else, say "PivotChart",  that is how the table will be displayed in the subform control.